# struts2 and spring transactions

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-transactions

I have a app written with struts2 and spring and JPA over hibernate. Form spring i use transactions and IoC.
My app is structured in 2 layers : Struts Actions and some "services" classes that are dealing with CRUD operations, classes that are annotated with @Transactional.
If in one of these services classes method an exception occurs i have to throw that exception from this class(to struts action level) in order for Spring to rollback transaction automatically, right?

What will happen otherwise (if a don`t throw that exception and the transaction will never rollback) ?

PS. i use spring managed EntityManager for all DB operations.

Thanks

Comment: i believe rollbacking transaction is entirely dependent on your spring transaction handling and it has nothing to do with struts2 action component.

Comment: my question was: if i throw an exception form a class marked as @Transactional (instance of this class is called from a struts2 action) will spring rollback the current transaction ?

Comment: You have to configure spring for making roll back based on certain transaction and it should not be an issue from where you are calling

Comment: We have same issue, we are calling some service layers method and we have OptimisticLockException in one of them, it comes back to the Action Struts class and there we can not handle or capture the exception (for two purpose, showing our custom error page and rollback the transaction after that manually) but we did not have any luck in it. Spring-Hibernate does not allow us to rollback the transaction in the Action method. so we switched to Lock API to handle this.